# Marshal a JSON Marshal compatible map to XML

Tags: arrays, xml, go, marshalling

I have a map: `[]map[string]string`.

Populating the results in a `json.marshal()` compatible object. Outputing:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "randval3": "val1",
    "randval2": "xyz1"
    "randval1": "xyz3"
  },
  ...
]
```

However, when I run `xml.marshal()`. I receive a `xml: unsupported type: map[string]string`. Which seems reasonable given the fact that XML needs node names etc. So what I'm basically looking for is a way to get:

```xml
<rootElement>
    <child>
        <key1>val1</key1>
        <key2>val1</key2>
    </child>
    <child>
        <randval3>val1</randval3>
        <randval2>xyz1</randval2>
        <randval1>xyz1</randval1>
    </child>
</rootElement>
```

But I'm getting stuck with getting an 'object' compatible with `xml.unmarshal()`

Comment: You should be able to do this with structs and slices.

Comment: So the struct part is a problem. I'm unable to generate a struct that is dynamic. Because the only things that are 'fixed' are 'child' and 'rootElement'

Comment: You could declare a custom map type and have it implement the xml.Unmarshaler interface.

Comment: @BenjamindeBos I guess you're stuck with manually parsing the xml tree. Here's a documented approach of what you're looking for https://medium.com/@jhxjohn/dynamic-xml-parse-to-json-in-go-lang-e8196752e47f

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/HXmOF-f_sD3

Comment: @mkopriva, single nodes go well, that is no problem. I need a struct for type []map[string]string

Comment: @BenjamindeBos Nothing stops you from doing that, as said in the first comment, struct & slices are supported out of the box.

Comment: @mkopriva The main problem here was the lack of basic knowledge of terminology within Golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a custom map and have it implement the `xml.Marshaler` interface.

```
type mymap map[string]string

func (m mymap) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if err := e.EncodeToken(start); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for key, val := range m {
        s := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: key}}
        if err := e.EncodeElement(val, s); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return e.EncodeToken(start.End())
}

type RootElement struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"rootElement"`
    Children []mymap  `xml:"child"`
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/0_qA9UUvhKV

```
func main() {
    root := RootElement{Children: []mymap{
        {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"},
        {"randval1": "val1", "randval2": "xyz1", "randval3": "abc3"},
    }}

    data, err := xml.MarshalIndent(root, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

output:

```
<rootElement>
  <child>
    <key2>val2</key2>
    <key1>val1</key1>
  </child>
  <child>
    <randval3>abc3</randval3>
    <randval1>val1</randval1>
    <randval2>xyz1</randval2>
  </child>
</rootElement>
```

Comment: That is awesome. That's exactly what i need. Maybe a bit of a basic question: But how would i get my already existing `type []map[string]string` converted into a `DataContentMap` type? Would a loop do the trick or is there a way to cast it?

Comment: You'll have to use a loop. As an alternative you could implement the xml.Marshaler interface on a slice of maps, then you'll be able to do a simple conversion: https://play.golang.com/p/Q_bnirBYOf6

Comment: You sir, are a life-saver. Thanks so much for your time and effort! Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For Marshalling/Unmarshalling maps you need to write your own `Marshal()` and `Unmarshal()` functions.

Below an example for implementing these functions for `type Maps []map[string]string` and how to use them.

```
type Maps []map[string]string

type xmlMapEntry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (m Maps) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if len(m) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    err := e.EncodeToken(start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, ma := range m {
        for k, v := range ma {
            e.Encode(xmlMapEntry{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: k}, Value: v})
        }
    }

    return e.EncodeToken(start.End())
}

func (m *Maps) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    *m = Maps{}

    for {
        var e xmlMapEntry

        err := d.Decode(&e)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        *m = append(*m, map[string]string{e.XMLName.Local: e.Value})
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    myarraymap := []map[string]string{
        0: {"Key1": "val1"},
        1: {"Key2": "val2"},
        2: {"Randval3": "val1"},
        3: {"Randval2": "xyz1"},
        4: {"Randval1": "xyz2"},
    }

    // Encode to XML
    x, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(Maps(myarraymap), "", "  ")
    fmt.Printf("my marshaled xml map: %v\n", string(x))


    // Decode back from XML
    var rm []map[string]string
    xml.Unmarshal(x, (*Maps)(&rm))
    fmt.Printf("my unmarshalled xml map: %v \n", rm)
}
```