# Is there a way to convert go struct with map inside it to xml

Tags: xml, go

I have two struct Person and Address with address inside Person.
I want xml in below form, with map inside struct, if using directy xml.Unmarshall, it seems not to be working.

```
<Person>
<id>101</id>
<address>
<key>1001</key>
<street>street</street>
</address>
<address>
<key>1001</key>
<street>street</street>
</address>
</Person>

type Person struct {
    Id string `xml:"id"`
    AddressMap map[string]Address
}
type Address struct {
    street string
}

address := Address{
    street: "Bangalore",
}
addressMap := make(map[string]Address)
addressMap["101"] = address
person := &Person{
    Id: "202",
    AddressMap: addressMap,
}
```

Comment: Declare a new map type and have it implement the `xml.Marshaler` interface. For an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266933/marshal-a-json-marshal-compatible-map-to-xml

Comment: I have tried for the same object , but not wrked

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what you want (followed from the link @mkopriva posted).

NB: I think the structure of the data is *odd*. It would make more sense (at least to me) to have a user's addresses as `[]Address`.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/xml"

type Person struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
    Id         string
    AddressMap AddressMap
}
type Address struct {
    Street string
}

func main() {
    addressOne := Address{
        Street: "Bangalore",
    }
    addressTwo := Address{
        Street: "Paris",
    }
    addressMap := make(map[string]Address)
    addressMap["101"] = addressOne
    addressMap["102"] = addressTwo
    person := &Person{
        Id:         "202",
        AddressMap: addressMap,
    }

    out, err := xml.MarshalIndent(person, " ", "  ")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}

type AddressMap map[string]Address

func (m AddressMap) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for key, val := range m {
        s := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "address"}}
        type customStruct struct {
            Key    string `xml:"key"`
            Street string `xml:"street"`
        }
        if err := e.EncodeElement(customStruct{
            Key:    key,
            Street: val.Street,
        }, s); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Outputs:

```xml
 <Person>
   <Id>202</Id>
   <address>
     <key>101</key>
     <street>Bangalore</street>
   </address>
   <address>
     <key>102</key>
     <street>Paris</street>
   </address>
 </Person>
```